# Firestore - trouble writing/reading nested data

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I'm new to Firestore and trying to get a few basic operations going.

I'd like to do something like this:

```
db.collection('quotes').doc().collection('productsOrdered').add({
```

This gives me an auto ID for the **quotes** document in the console (in *italics*) and on the **productsOrdered** document, non-italic. However, I don't seem to be able to get the data in the **quotes** document, even using the ID in the query. I understand that *italics* is normally used in the console because a collection has been deleted but not the underlying documents.

How/why do the italics correlate to writing data in the way shown in the code above? Is it possible to write data with autoID's in this way, if so how?

Thanks

Comment: Your code creates a `productsOrdered` sub-collection under a new `quotes` document. It does not add any data to the new `quotes` document, so that document can't be read. I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to accomplish here, beyond creating a new sub-collection.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen - You're right. I was trying to do two things at once but it doesn't help. Thanks for the comment!